# LibreOffice Calc: Fix first columns when scolling to the right

Tags: libreoffice-calc

Suppose you have a table in `localc` where the first two columns contain names of people for example and the other columns some information about each person. If I have too many info columns, I have to scroll to the right to see them. However, I can't then see the names any more (such that it is difficult to see to which person the info belongs).

Is there any way to ensure that the first two columns are viewed/fixed when you scroll to the right? (Id est, only the other columns scroll.)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just realized the answer by myself:

Just click on the cell for which you want cells above and to the left of to be frozen. Then, click on `Window->Freeze`.